# Microsoft Exchange / E-mail / Restore from Journaling Mailbox

Tags: email, exchange

Would any Microsoft Exchange (2013) admins know the best way to parse a journaling mailbox to re-create a user's mailbox?  (this isn't my exact requirement, but is simpler to explain and accomplishes the same goal).

For example, I want Exchange to find all e-mails FROM (or) TO "thisuser" and make a new mailbox with every single e-mail, so even deleted ones will be seen (since the journal was setup to copy every inbound and outbound e-mail).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technet has all the information you could want:  [Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353189%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Depending on your preference for a GUI or PowerShell you can follow the instructions to create a new discovery search against a mailbox or against the entire organization.  You can put the items on **in-place hold** if needed.  With your search results in hand, you can then export the items to a PST or another mailbox (Discovery mailbox, typically).

Generally speaking you will want to review the search results for validity before exporting.